# Data mining with Python

Tags: python

I met some problem when I was doing assignments.

```
import re

fconn=open('reviews.html')
html=fconn.read()#read the entire html into this variable
fconn.close()

#find all the matches of the given expression
matches=re.finditer('<div id="R.*?" class="a-section review".*?\
<span class="a-icon-alt">(.*?) out of 5 stars</span>.*?\
<a class="a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold" href="/gp/.*?>(.*?)</a>.*?\
<a class="a-size-base a-link-normal author" href="/gp/.*?>(.*?)</a>.*?\
<span class="a-size-base a-color-secondary review-date">(.*?)</span>.*?',html)



matches2=re.finditer(('<div id="R.*?" class="a-section review".*?\
<span class="a-icon-alt">(.*?) out of 5 stars</span>.*?\
<a class="a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold" href="/gp/.*?>(.*?)</a>.*?\
<a class="a-size-base a-link-normal author" href="/gp/.*?>(.*?)</a>.*?\
<span class="a-size-base a-color-secondary review-date">(.*?)</span>.*?\
<span class="a-size-mini a-color-state a-text-bold">(.*?)</span>.*?',html)



for M in matches:
    stars=M.group(1)
    title=M.group(2)
    user=M.group(3)
    date=M.group(4)    
    print stars,title,user,date


for M2 in matches2:
    stars=M.group(1)
    title=M.group(2)
    user=M.group(3)
    date=M.group(4)
    purchase=M.group(5)    
    print stars,title,user,date,purchase
```

The problem is `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
Then I found out that when there is only one match in this program there is no such problem. So can someone tell me how to handle this one? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the superfluous opening brace in

```
matches2=re.finditer(('<di...
```

If you find fiddling with `regex` of that complexity annoying, you could consider some library like `BeautifulSoup` to parse HTML...